# Relation between sum of combinations

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I just realised the following identity: 
$$\sum_{i=0}^n {2n+1\choose i}=\sum_{i=0}^{2n}{2n\choose i}.$$
Is that correct? Has this been already proved?

Comment: You mean $2^{2n} = \frac12\cdot 2^{2n+1}$?

Comment: oh, yeah, binomial expansion will work here, and the fact that combinations repeat themselves. true?

Comment: It's true that the sum of the entries of any row of Pascal's triangle is twice the sum of the entries of the preceding row. It is a symmetry fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the identity holds and, as remarked by Ted Shifrin, it is equivalent to $\displaystyle 2^{2n} = \frac12\cdot 2^{2n+1}$.

By the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), we have that  that
$$2^{2n}=(1+1)^{2n}=\sum_{i=0}^{2n}{2n\choose i}$$
and, since $\binom{m}{k}=\binom{m}{m-k}$,
$$
\begin{align}2^{2n+1}&=(1+1)^{2n+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{2n+1} {2n+1\choose i}=\sum_{i=0}^{n} {2n+1\choose i}+\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n+1} {2n+1\choose i}\\&=\sum_{i=0}^{n} {2n+1\choose i}+\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n+1} {2n+1\choose 2n+1-i}
=\sum_{i=0}^{n} {2n+1\choose i}+\sum_{j=0}^{n} {2n+1\choose j}\\&=2\sum_{i=0}^{n} {2n+1\choose i}.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 0}^{n}{2n + 1 \choose i} & =
{1 \over 2}\sum_{i = 0}^{2n + 1}{2n + 1 \choose i} =
{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\sum_{i = 0}^{2n}
\bracks{{2n \choose i} + {2n \choose i - 1}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\sum_{i = 0}^{2n}{2n \choose i} +
{1 \over 2}\sum_{i = 1}^{2n}{2n \choose i - 1} =
{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\sum_{i = 0}^{2n}{2n \choose i} +
{1 \over 2}\sum_{i = 0}^{2n - 1}{2n \choose i}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\sum_{i = 0}^{2n}{2n \choose i} +
{1 \over 2}\bracks{\sum_{i = 0}^{2n}{2n \choose i} - 1} =
\bbx{\sum_{i = 0}^{2n}{2n \choose i}}
\end{align}